# How can I trim the carriage return from text that is being piped in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting, echo

I'm using this command to get my last typed command:

```
history | cut -c 8- | tail -n 2 | head -n 1
```

It works very well in bash, removing the line numbers, but there is one problem I have with it, (er, annoyance, because I want just the command) and I'm piping this to the `xsel` clipboard manager:

**It also grabs the trailing new line / carriage return...**

I know in some shells you can use:

```
echo "text \c"
```

I'm not sure how to incorporate that into `bash` though.

Extra points for the solution that is easiest to type on the fly :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the last command in your history with the bash builtin `!!` and use `echo -n` to print that command without a newline character at the end:

```
echo -n !!
```

The `!!` argument will expand to the actual command string and `-n` makes sure the output contains no newline character.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question correctly, you need to remove the trailing newline. Try this perl bit: `perl -ne 'chomp and print'

Examples:

```
[root@talara test]# ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun  7 21:30 .
dr-xr-x---. 28 root root 4096 Jun  8 08:42 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 Jun  7 15:10 FILE1
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun  7 14:49 ham
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   36 Jun  7 21:31 t
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   11 Jun  7 16:21 test

[root@talara test]# ls -la | perl -ne 'chomp and print'
total 20drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun  7 21:30 .dr-xr-x---. 28 root root 4096 Jun  8 08:42 ..-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 Jun  7 15:10 FILE1drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun  7 14:49 ham-rw-r--r--   1 root root   36 Jun  7 21:31 t-rw-r--r--   1 root root   11 Jun  7 16:21 test
```

And to make it easy for typing over and over and on the fly you can make an alias: `alias chomp="perl -ne 'chomp and print'"`